# how to change portal url in Dnn?

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

I am working on dnn, I have one parent portal and two child portals.
my parent portal have a URL like(www.abc.com/abc) but i have to change it sub subdirectory to main Url that is www.abc.com how it will possible in dnn?

Answer (score 1):

In the web.config you'll find an entry that looks like:

```
<add key="HostHeader" value="" />
<!-- Host Header to remove from URL so "www.mydomain.com/johndoe/Default.aspx" is treated as "www.mydomain.com/Default.aspx" -->
```

Just fill this out and it should fix your problem.

```
<add key="HostHeader" value="abc" />
<!-- Host Header to remove from URL so "www.mydomain.com/johndoe/Default.aspx" is treated as "www.mydomain.com/Default.aspx" -->
```